# How to allow camera permissions persistently on macOS?

Tags: macos, electron

I am developing an Electron app and, for some reason, I am asked to allow camera permission each time I run app.

I am using following code in renderer process.

```js
stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints)
video.srcObject = stream
video.setAttribute("playsinline", true)
video.play()
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 2):

It appears issue is caused by code signing on macOS Big Sur / M1 (see https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/31490).

Manually signing app using following command fixes issue.

> Heads-up: replace `QR\ Bridge.app` with name of app to sign.

```
codesign --force --deep --sign - /Applications/QR\ Bridge.app
```

Comment: Worked for me on MacOS BigSur v11.5.2 and Electron v12.2.3.